# Probability puzzle solved by R simulation; answer close but not exactly. Bug in my code?

Tags: r, probability, simulation, puzzle

Here's an interesting probablity puzzle:

> One hundred people line up to board an airplane. Each has a boarding
>   pass with assigned seat. However, the first person to board has lost
>   his boarding pass and takes a random seat. After that, each person
>   takes the assigned seat if it is unoccupied, and one of unoccupied
>   seats at random otherwise. What is the probability that the last
>   person to board gets to sit in his assigned seat?

Now, the analytical approach gives an answer of 50%.

I tried writing a R simulation & I'm consistently getting something like 47%. Even on increasing the sim size. Do I have a corner-case bug?

```
max_pax<-100
max_sims<-100

last_pax_match<-0

for(sims in seq(1:max_sims))
{
  assigned_seats<-sample(max_pax,max_pax,replace = F)#indexed by pax no
  actual_seats<-rep(0,100) #indexed by seat

  first_pax_seat_no<-sample(max_pax,1)
  actual_seats[first_pax_seat_no]<-1
  for(pax in seq(2:max_pax-1))
  {
    if(actual_seats[assigned_seats[pax]]==0)
    {
      actual_seats[assigned_seats[pax]]<-pax
    }
    else
    {
      empty_seats<-which(actual_seats==0)
      random_seat<-sample(x=empty_seats,1)
      actual_seats[random_seat]<-pax
    }

  }
  if(actual_seats[assigned_seats[max_pax]]==0)
  {
    last_pax_match<-last_pax_match+1
  }
}
last_pax_match/max_sims*100
```

Comment: Interesting as the puzzle may be, you're still asking us simply to help debug R code, so I think this question would be more appropriate for http://stackoverflow.com/ with the `r` tag.

Comment: Note that there's no need to write `seq(1:max_sims)`. It's just `1:max_sims`. Have a look at what `seq(2:max_pax-1)` is. Is that really what you want? I haven't tried to understand the details of what you're doing, but I suspect you instead want `2:(max_pax - 1)`.

Comment: @JakeWestfall "Here's a bunch of code. What did I do wrong?" isn't a popular question type on StackOverflow either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mark999 is right. Replace line 13 with

```
for(pax in 2:(max_pax-1))
```

and you'll get the right answer.

---

Also, `actual_seats<-rep(0,max_pax)` is more general than `actual_seats<-rep(0,100)`